# how to change URL from this to another?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web, dns

I have a url that is something like `forum.example.com` but want to change that to something else, so the question is how do i change-

`forum.example.com` to `www.example.com/forum/`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This site is intended as a programming Q&A. For questions like this about server configuration, you might want to head over to http://SuperUser.com/. You also might want to improve your question by adding what you've done to try to solve this yourself, along with the results you got. And fix your tags. (Are you *really* asking about DNS?)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forum.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/forum/$1 [L, QSA]
```